# How to save two workbooks as and mirror the connections that they contain

Tags: vba

I need some conceptual help from those more experienced than me --
I know you guys usually like code but I have many pages of code on this project and my question is not regarding any code I have but rather how I might code something I have not been able to figure out. 
So basically I have two workbooks whose main purpose is labor tracking. one is the control workbook that has all my code, the other is a workbook where reports are made by field workers. The reason the field workbook cannot have code is because it will be operated from an ipad which I believe cannot yet run VBA. I know how to establish the connections necessary, however for every project a new copy of both the workbooks need to be made. I already have functions that clear out, reset and save the main workbook however I am struggling with the connected workbook. I know how to save the connected workbook, but I was  hoping to preserve the connections between the two old workbooks when I run the macro that saves them as and also mirror those connections between the new workbooks. Is this possible or will I need clear all connections and re establish them every time a new set of job books needs to be created?

===> EDIT: I believe that I need to embed the report book into the main book, but that still begs the question on how I save the embedded workbook as at the same time I save the main workbook as in order to create a new book with all the same connections

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "connection" here?  Linked cells?

Comment: Yeah I was going to do a web of linked cells through data connections and try to have the whole thing duplicate but it really didnt seem like that would be reliable so I scratched the whole idea and just went about it with some dynamic resizing and setting ranges equal with vba